# Can an ADF pipeline change its Concurrency number based on a calculated condition?

Tags: azure-data-factory

**Background**

I have an ADF pipeline that takes jobs from a “3rd party” queue (ueing a REST call), completes jobs and marks the queued message as complete. If the queue is empty, the pipeline ends. Otherwise, the pipeline loops until the queue is empty.

I can scale the pipeline by creating multiple “Scheduled” triggers running every one minute.
I can control the number of the pipeline instances running by changing its Concurrency numbers.

[image]

**Question**

Is there any way the ADF pipeline changes its Concurrency number based on a calculated condition such as the queue length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you can give only **numeric hardcoded** values in concurrency settings and there is no option to pass the value dynamically.

Reference: [Azure Data Factory Pipeline Concurrency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-pipelines-activities?tabs=data-factory#pipeline-json)